# Apache Pig Mapreduce Mode

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

i'm getting the following exception while try to run pig in mapreduce mode,

ERROR 4010: Cannot find hadoop configurations in classpath (neither hadoop-site.xml nor core-site.xml was found in the classpath). If you plan to use local mode, please put -x local option in command line

I have the following hadoop class path set,

export HADOOP_INSTALL=/media/Software/hadoop-1.0.4

Thanks

Comment: You probably didn't set the Hadoop conf dir in `PIG_CLASSPATH`. See section _Running the Pig Scripts in Mapreduce Mode_ : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/start.html

Comment: Thanks!, the following helped, export PIG_CLASSPATH=/mycluster/conf, export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/mycluster/conf